# view in another view page not getting displayed

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I want to display `Welcome to my 3rd Blog!` of `blogvieww.php` in 
`blogview.php` using codegniter.

But in the code below, what I've tried is that even `Welcome to my 2nd Blog!` of `blogvieww.php` is getting displayed in `blogview.php`.

Actually I just want to display only `Welcome to my 3rd Blog!`, how to do this can any one tell please tell me where my mistake was?

**Blogcontroller.php(controller file)**

```
<?php  
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

    class Blogcontroller extends CI_Controller {  

        public function index()  
        {  
            $data['blogvieww'] = $this->load->view('blogvieww', '', TRUE);
            $this->load->view('blogview', $data);  
        }  

        public function blogvieww()  
        {  
            $this->load->view('blogvieww');  
        } 
    }  
?>
```

**blogview.php (view file)**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div><?php echo $blogvieww; ?></div>
            <h1>Welcome to my 1st Blog!</h1>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**blogvieww.php (view file)**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>Welcome to my 2nd Blog!</h1></div>
        <div><h1>Welcome to my 3rd Blog!</h1></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: print the $data['blogvieww'] before move to view so you can get idea?

Comment: Why you want to do that. It can be doing in another way.

Comment: did not got you sir @DsRaj

Comment: echo $data['blogvieww'];exit; add these code before $this->load->view('blogview', $data); Line

Comment: sir when i did that na then the content which is their in "blogview.php" that is "Welcome to my 1st Blog!" got vanished

Comment: Welcome to my 2nd Blog! &  Welcome to my 3rd Blog! is getting displayed

Comment: please guide me sir im trying it from yesterday please sir

Answer (score 0):

Change in your `blogview.php`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div><?php echo $data->blogvieww; ?></div>
        <h1>Welcome to my 1st Blog!</h1>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```